# python3 algebraic expression solve for x

Tags: python, python-3.x, algebra

I'm relatively new to python, and decided to make a calculator.  Unfortunately I cant solve for x.  The error is:

> SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target.

I can't figure out any way around this as I want to have the person enter in the problem, and then it prints x.

Please help, And thanks for any help in advance.

My code:

```
import random
from datetime import datetime
import time
def ints(x,y): 
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)
now = datetime.now()
def solve(c, z):
    c = (*z)
print(now.year)
time.sleep(1)
print("WELCOME TO THE JERAXXUS SOFTWARE")
time.sleep(2)
math = True
if math == True:
    user_input = input("My name is jeraxxus, please put in 2 numbers followed by a operator, *, /, +, -, **, or %.  No commas please")
    user_input = str.split(user_input)
    a_list = [user_input]
    n1 = user_input[0]
    n2 = user_input[1]
    operate = user_input[2]
    algebra = input("does your mathmatical equation contain algebraic values?")
    if algebra == 'no':
        if operate == '*':
            n1 = int(n1)
            n2 = int(n2)
            print(n1 * n2)
        elif operate == '/':
            n1 = int(n1)
            n2 = int(n2)
            print(n1 / n2)
        elif operate == '+':
            n1 = int(n1)
            n2 = int(n2)
            print(n1 + n2)
        elif operate == '-':
            n1 = int(n1)
            n2 = int(n2)
            print(n1 - n2)
        elif operate == '**':
            n1 = int(n1)
            n2 = int(n2)
            print(n1 ** n2)
        elif operate == '%':
            n1 = int(n1)
            n2 = int(n2)
            print(n1 % n2)
        elif operate != '%' and operate!= '**' and operate != '-' and operate != '+' and operate != '/' and operate != '*':
            print("SHAME YOU SHOULD HAVE FOLLOWED MY COMMANDS")
            math = False
    elif algebra == 'yes':
        problem = input("please state your algebraic problems with spaces after each operation and number, the order is crucial please have only 1 variable and have it first.")
        problem = str.split(problem)
        lop = problem[0]
        b_list = [problem]
        sovle(lop, b_list)
```

Comment: post full stacktrace.

Comment: what is `c = (*z)` supposed to do?

Comment: Please post the **full text** of the stack trace. It should point to a specific line.

Comment: c = *z should have a variable assigned to the answer, and then i print the variable

Comment: @njzk2 the line is the last one,  the solve function.

Comment: I don't understand what you expect that line to do exactly. did you try to look at the content of the variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are a few thing about your code:

the function `ints` do nothing in the end because you don't return any value, the error that you get come from `c=(*z)` you can't do that in a assignation, but you can do it in a function call like this `fun(*argument_list)`.

The variable `math` as used there is useless because you assign it True and check it for that same value, so you enter in that `if` block unconditionally meaning that that `if math == True` is unneeded, maybe you mean `while math` that way you repeat that block while the variable `math` is true.

What is the reason of the variable `a_list`?, you don't use it.

In the block `if algebra == 'no'` you can put int conversions first and then check the `operate` so to avoid repeat the same code over and over again, speaking of `operate` the last `elif` is redundant because if you get there it is because it fail the other comparisons so no need to check again against every possibility, change it for a simple `else`.

with that little revisions you code will look like this

```
import random
from datetime import datetime
import time

def solve(c, z):
    raise NotImplementedError("In process of programming") # an error because there is still no code for this

now = datetime.now()
print(now.year)
time.sleep(1)
print("WELCOME TO THE JERAXXUS SOFTWARE")
time.sleep(2)
math = True
while math:
    user_input = input("My name is jeraxxus, please put in 2 numbers followed by a operator, *, /, +, -, **, or %.  No commas please")
    user_input = str.split(user_input)
    #a_list = [user_input]
    n1 = user_input[0]
    n2 = user_input[1]
    operate = user_input[2]
    algebra = input("does your mathematical equation contain algebraic values?")
    if algebra == 'no':
        n1 = int(n1)
        n2 = int(n2)
        if operate == '*':
            print(n1 * n2)
        elif operate == '/':
            print(n1 / n2)
        elif operate == '+':
            print(n1 + n2)
        elif operate == '-':
            print(n1 - n2)
        elif operate == '**':
            print(n1 ** n2)
        elif operate == '%':
            print(n1 % n2)
        else:
            print("SHAME YOU SHOULD HAVE FOLLOWED MY COMMANDS")
            math = False
    elif algebra == 'yes':
        problem = input("please state your algebraic problems with spaces after each operation and number, the order is crucial please have only 1 variable and have it first.")
        problem = str.split(problem)
        lop = problem[0]
        b_list = [problem]
        solve(lop, b_list)
```

The no algebra part work fine, you need now figure the solve x part, if you need help with this too, just ask :)

**Simple calculator**

After quick search, making a simple calculator in python is easy with the use of `eval`, like this

```
def calculator():
    exp = input("x= ")
    print("x=", eval(exp) )
```

with this you can procesate any valid python expression as if you were in the IDLE.

But if for academics reason you don't want to use it, then as I tell you before, you have to make a parser of mathematical expressions, that identificate what operator is in there and arrange them according to its precedence and finally solve the expresion

Comment: That is what i needed help with, sorry for the confusion, and I was working on the ints function but I stopped, and forgot to delete it sorry

Comment: ok, lets brainstorm: what kind of equations you want to solve? this: `a=b*x + c ` with a,b,c number, `a=b op x op c ` the same but with op one of the operator or with a,b,c any kind of expression without x or `exp_const = exp_x` where exp_const is any expression with only number and operator and exp_x the same but with one or more occurrence x ??? In general you have to make a parser of mathematical expression, and with that resolve for x in a similar way you do by hand

Comment: I want it to be able to solve any equation, where x would be equal to the equation, or the list.  What i imagine this program doing is assigning a list to x, where the total of that would be x, solving the equation.

Comment: any kind of equation, maybe you should look at the numpy modulo it should have tools to solve any kind of polynomial equation and system of equations and any other function because attacking ANY kind of equation is more complicate of what you may think and to some of then you may never find a solution like this `0=x**2+1` or `0=x**2 +x +1` they have no solution in Real numbers. On the other hand, if you want to doing yourself I can think of a way of doing it but only if it is a monomial equation, I mean this kind `a=b*x**c +d` where a,b,c,d are any number.

Comment: I am no sure what you mean with a list, can you give a example?

Comment: basically what i'm trying to do would be x = 1 + 3 ** 5.  So that you assign x to the list, and it computes itself.  So if the list would be b_list[1, +, 3, **, 5], it would assign itself to the numerical values of that, if that makes any sense.

Comment: I fixed the original error, but now i can't get the list into a commutable form, please help.

Comment: if that is the type of equations that you are trying to solve, then that is easy, that is no different of a simple calculator, futhermore a quick search tell that making a calculator in python is pretty easy with the use of `eval` function. Let me show you.

Comment: I understand how to use the eval function, but i cant figure out how to turn it into a computable eval form, str, int, or float.

Comment: if you give eval a expression that result in a int, that is what you get, you can also do str(eval(exp))

Comment: Thank you SO SO SO much for the help

Comment: Glad that help you. Remember to be careful with the use of eval, don't use if you can't trust you user, because a malicious user can insert something that went execute by eval may ruin your day...